# Symmetry condition for continuous coordinate transformations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, definition

Considering a continuous coordinate transformation defined as
$q_i(\epsilon,t)=q_i(t)+\epsilon\eta_i(t)$ and a Lagrangian $L(q_i,\dot{q_i},t)$. The symmetry condition for a system described by these can be written as $\frac{dL}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}=0$. How can you explain it ?

Comment: Is this not the *definition* of the symmetry of a Lagrangian? If so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: A symmetry is an operation  that leaves an object  unchanged, so a symmetry of Lagrangian is an operation that leaves the Lagrangian unchanged. I can't  think of what else you might need as an explanation. Such symmetries lead to conserved quantities via Nother's theorem, which is why they are useful.

Comment: But why is the condition evaluated in $\epsilon$=0

Comment: @Herbert: It's evaluated there because we're evaluating a derivative, albeit in an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am totally nwe to this type of analytical mechanics. I understand what symmetry means but I don´t know how to exactly explain why L derivated in $\epsilon$ (and then replace $\epsilon$ with 0) = 0 means symmetry. Can you explain with some more detail please ? That´s what I have to do in my assignment